# SQL UPDATE for float field not working mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, xampp

My database has `float` field on `gh_rg_lead_detail` table

```
field_number    float
```

In the database I am trying to uodate all `12.2` to `9.2` but it seems my query didn't work.
this is my query

```
UPDATE `gh_rg_lead_detail` SET `field_number`=9.2 WHERE`field_number`= 12.2
```

did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `gh_rg_lead_detail` SET `field_number`=9.2 WHERE
CAST(`field_number` AS DECIMAL(10,1) )= 12.2
```